# Terraform aws provider within module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 AWS accounts **A** and **B**

Also, I have a self-managed terraform module which has resources that should be applied in account **A**, like below

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_association" "main" {
  provider = aws.account_a

  transit_gateway_attachment_id  = aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.main.id
  transit_gateway_route_table_id = var.transit_gateway_rtb_association
}
```

Then in account **B**, I have configuration for the account   **A**  aws provider

```
provider "aws" {
  alias   = "account_a"
  profile = "account_a_profile"
  region  = "us-east-2"
}
```

My issue is when I'm applying my module in account **B** - all pass fine, but when I remove profile row  `profile = "account_a_profile"` it wants to create resources in account **B** which is wrong because `aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_association` resource from my module has a provider configuration which relies on the account **A**

Below is my module code

```
module "my_module" {
  source = ""

  providers = {
    aws.account_a = aws.account_a
  }

  vpc_id                             = module.vpc.vpc_id
  transit_gateway_attachment_subnets = module.vpc.private_subnets
  private_route_table_ids            = module.vpc.private_route_table_ids

  transit_gateway_id              = data.terraform_remote_state.account_a.outputs.transit_gateway_id
  transit_gateway_rtb_association = data.terraform_remote_state.account_a.outputs.transit_gateway_route_tables["main"].id
  transit_gateway_rtb_propagation = [data.terraform_remote_state.account_a.outputs.transit_gateway_route_tables["service"].id]
```

What should I do to make my code in the account B idempotent?

Comment: And why do you want to remove the account A provider definition?

Comment: I'm not removing the entire account A provider definition, just the profile row. This is necessary because I need to push that code to Git, and other engineers might have different profile names for that provider.

Comment: Ah, ok, well then you can define a variable, e.g., `variable "profile_a_name" {type = string }` and leave it to the developer to specify the name and then do `profile = var.profile_a_name`

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution. However, why does it attempt to create those resources in account B when the resource has a statically defined provider with account A?

Comment: If you don't specify the `profile` argument then the AWS provider will take settings from your system's _default_ profile. If you are intending to use profiles to distinguish between multiple provider configurations in the same Terraform configuration then it'd be better to always explicitly set `profile`, so that the default configuration can never apply. This is a general AWS configuration behavior, not specific to the Terraform AWS provider; see [Using Named Profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html#cli-configure-files-using-profiles).

Comment: Okay, but I still can't understand why it tries to apply resources from the module when there is a static provider setting of another AWS account?

Comment: In my experience, when there are some nonsense things with Terraform provider I usually do `TF_LOG=DEBUG` just to see the exact call sent to AWS, then if the context allow it (i.e. not a production environment) a `terraform init -upgrade` or a`terraform init -reconfigure`